# Using an ARM template, C#, getting errors when deploying a private git repo to an Azure App Service

Tags: git, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a private repo that I need to programmatically deploy to an Azure App Service. It works just fine with a public repo, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out the magic of getting authentication to work.

This fine link ([Deploying website from private Github repository using ARM Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239397/deploying-website-from-private-github-repository-using-arm-templates)) is exactly the same problem, but it doesn't have an accepted answer and I have tried everything in there to no avail.

I have created a personal access token and generated something like this for my repoURL

```
https://username:accesstoken@github.com/orgname/reponame.git
```

I still get a 404 because it can't find the private repo.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with Github deploy keys. I have created some, but I am not sure how to use them since the server, by its very nature of being dynamic, doesn't exist beforehand and I can't install anything on it. My guess is that somehow Azure itself needs to create a deploy key and install it, but I am not sure how to make that happen.

I am guessing that this is done all the time, but I just can't find the right link....