# Web App created from ARM template - can't disconnect deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I created a web app, app plan and resource group using a template adapted from that generated on the Azure portal, and the powershell script that is also from the azure portal.

It failed to link to my bitbucket repo or install an extension but was otherwise successful.

However, if I try to disconnect my deployment in the Deployment Center to connect to Bitbucket manually, it just shows the three dots busy animation but never finishes. See screenshot attached:
[image]

Below is my template.json (yes I know it's a mess, I'm still learning!):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sites_webapp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "cdg-grav-demo01",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "serverfarms_appplan_name": {
            "defaultValue": "cus-box-appplan",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "config_web_name": {
            "defaultValue": "web",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Serverfarm Size",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "sku": {
                "name": "F1",
                "tier": "Free",
                "size": "F1",
                "family": "F",
                "capacity": 0
            },
            "kind": "app",
            "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_appplan_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "location": "Central US",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('serverfarms_appplan_name')]",
                "workerTierName": null,
                "adminSiteName": null,
                "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
                "perSiteScaling": false,
                "reserved": false,
                "targetWorkerCount": 0,
                "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Site Parameters",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "app",
            "name": "[parameters('sites_webapp_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "Central US",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_webapp_name'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "virtualIP": null,
                        "thumbprint": null,
                        "toUpdate": null,
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_webapp_name'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "virtualIP": null,
                        "thumbprint": null,
                        "toUpdate": null,
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                ],
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_appplan_name'))]",
                "reserved": false,
                "siteConfig": null,
                "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
                "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
                "clientCertEnabled": false,
                "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                "containerSize": 0,
                "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                "cloningInfo": null,
                "httpsOnly": true
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarms_appplan_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Site Settings",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_webapp_name'), '/', parameters('config_web_name'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "Central US",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php",
                    "hostingstart.html"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
                "phpVersion": "7.2",
                "pythonVersion": "",
                "nodeVersion": "",
                "linuxFxVersion": "",
                "windowsFxVersion": null,
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2017",
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "publishingUsername": "[concat('$',parameters('sites_webapp_name'))]",
                "publishingPassword": null,
                "appSettings": null,
                "azureStorageAccounts": {},
                "metadata": null,
                "connectionStrings": null,
                "machineKey": null,
                "handlerMappings": null,
                "documentRoot": null,
                "scmType": "BitbucketGit",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
                "webSocketsEnabled": false,
                "alwaysOn": false,
                "javaVersion": null,
                "javaContainer": null,
                "javaContainerVersion": null,
                "appCommandLine": "",
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false,
                        "virtualDirectories": null
                    }
                ],
                "winAuthAdminState": 0,
                "winAuthTenantState": 0,
                "customAppPoolIdentityAdminState": false,
                "customAppPoolIdentityTenantState": false,
                "runtimeADUser": null,
                "runtimeADUserPassword": null,
                "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
                "routingRules": [],
                "experiments": {
                    "rampUpRules": []
                },
                "limits": null,
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "autoHealRules": null,
                "tracingOptions": null,
                "vnetName": "",
                "siteAuthEnabled": false,
                "siteAuthSettings": {
                    "enabled": null,
                    "unauthenticatedClientAction": null,
                    "tokenStoreEnabled": null,
                    "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
                    "defaultProvider": null,
                    "clientId": null,
                    "clientSecret": null,
                    "clientSecretCertificateThumbprint": null,
                    "issuer": null,
                    "allowedAudiences": null,
                    "additionalLoginParams": null,
                    "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
                    "googleClientId": null,
                    "googleClientSecret": null,
                    "googleOAuthScopes": null,
                    "facebookAppId": null,
                    "facebookAppSecret": null,
                    "facebookOAuthScopes": null,
                    "twitterConsumerKey": null,
                    "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
                    "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
                    "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
                    "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": null
                },
                "cors": null,
                "push": null,
                "apiDefinition": null,
                "autoSwapSlotName": null,
                "localMySqlEnabled": false,
                "managedServiceIdentityId": null,
                "xManagedServiceIdentityId": null,
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": null,
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": null,
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": null,
                "http20Enabled": true,
                "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "ftpsState": "FtpsOnly",
                "reservedInstanceCount": 0
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_webapp_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Source Control",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_webapp_name'),'/SourceControl')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "Central US",
            "properties": {
              "repoUrl": "https://bitbucket.org/goldjg/cirrius-tech-blog",
              "branch": "develop",
              "isManualIntegration": false,
              "deploymentRollbackEnabled": false,
              "isMercurial": false,
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_webapp_name'))]"
            ]
            }
          },
          {
            "comments": "Site Extensions",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_webapp_name'),'/ComposerExtension')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "Central US",
            "properties": {
              "id": "ComposerExtension",
              "title": "Composer",
              "type": "Gallery",
              "extension_url": "[concat('https://',parameters('sites_webapp_name'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net/Composer/')]",
              "project_url": "https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension",
              "icon_url": "http://www.siteextensions.net/Content/Images/packageDefaultIcon.png",
              "license_url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT",
              "feed_url": null,
              "installer_command_line_params": null,
              "published_date_time": null,
              "local_path": "D:\\home\\SiteExtensions\\ComposerExtension",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_webapp_name'))]"
            ]
            }
          }
    ]
}
```

And here's my parameters.json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sites_webapp_name": {
            "value": "IAC-DEMO-01"
        },
        "serverfarms_appplan_name": {
            "value": "IACDEMO-Appplan"
        },
        "config_web_name": {
            "value": "web"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to follow below steps to disconnect the deployment in this case.

1. Go to https://resources.azure.com/ i.e., go to your newly created App service resource in Azure portal and click on 'Resource explorer' tile.
2. Now in Resource Explorer, go to config -> web.
3. Make sure you are in "Read/Write" mode rather than in "Read only" mode.
4. Click "Edit" to update the "web" JSON file.
5. Now change "scmType" key's value to "None".
6. Click "PUT".

Just a note on failed part is, AFAIK your template failed to link bitbucket repo because it could not find source control token for your bitbucket repo.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: That worked a treat - and introduced me to resource explorer - which is really useful!  Out of interest, how would I define the source control token in an ARM template?

Comment: The answer to your question is little tricky for external repositories like Bitbucket / GitHub.

Comment: To keep it simple and short, you may first authorize bitbucket deployment at least once using Azure portal to set up the relationship i.e., actually to setup continuous deployment an oauth token is required to call GitHub/Bitbucket apis. This token is given to Azure during OAuth consent flow on portal. If you run into this issue, try logon to portal (portal.azure.com) and perform setup continuous deployment once (to any site). The oauth token will be stored for the logon Azure user. Each Azure user will need to go thru OAuth consent flow once.

Comment: For more information and reference, please check below URL's.
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-continuous-deployment#q-get-exception-cannot-find-sourcecontroltoken-with-name-github and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239397/deploying-website-from-private-github-repository-using-arm-templates and https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#setting-up-continuous-deployment-using-manual-steps
Again, I hope this update helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: excellent - will give that a look and see how I get on. Even if I can’t get the source control and extensions done via an ARM template, doing the rest via template is still a huge help and that bit seems to have gone ok :-)