# Failure when settings continuous deployment of webapps on Azure

Tags: azure, github, continuous-deployment

When I try to set up continuous deployment through GitHub Actions on an App Service (either a Asp.NET app or a Node app), I get a `Failed to set up deployment: Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub` error.

I've ensured Azure App Service is authorized on my account's authorized OAuth Apps, but I haven't found any further instructions on whether there are any settings I must change on Github's side.

What I found here on SO was [Deploying website from private Github repository using ARM Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239397/deploying-website-from-private-github-repository-using-arm-templates), that pointed me to check whether there's a token set on `/providers/Microsoft.Web/sourcecontrols/GitHub` resource, which there is (token obscured by me of course):

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "GitHub",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sourcecontrols",
  "properties": {
    "name": "GitHub",
    "token": "***************************************",
    "tokenSecret": null,
    "refreshToken": null,
    "environment": null
  }
}
```

The same also happens if I try and set up CD with the App Service Build Service. I've tried changing the token already there for a new fresh token I manually generated on Github, but still, no go. The same happens with a different Github account as well. How should I set up CD for my Azure App Service?

Comment: Your Azure App Service is Windows/Linux?

Comment: It's a linux app. Continuous development setup with an ASP.NET API/Web App works with no issue.

Comment: Check the below answer for NodeJS Linux App.

Comment: I think it was an issue on Azure's side, as I tried just setting CD again, and it worked. Azure should invest in more meaningful error messages , though... Since the error was on their side, do I delete this question, or pick your answer as correct?

Comment: @Artr S - The below answer is reproduced in my environment with the NodeJS Azure Linux App Service. Iam able to deploy and run the app using GitHubActions without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps for Continuous deployment of Azure Web Apps.

- In Azure Portal Create an App Service.
  [image]
- Create a Node JS App from either `VSCode` or `Visual Studio` and push the source to GitHub Repository.
- From `Deployment Center` => `Settings` =>select the Source `GitHub` Under Continuous Deployment.
- We need to Authorize the GitHub Account and select the correct repository and branch.
  [image]
- Once we connect to the GitHub a new folder `.github/workflows` will be created with the `workflow`(yaml file).

**My Yml file***

```cs
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - NodeApp6Dec

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'NodeApp6Dec'
          slot-name: 'production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_acc907cfa07 }}
          package: .
```

***OutPut:***

[image]

- If you want to make any changes to the `yml` file, go to the `GitHub Repository` => `Workflows` => `.github/workflows` folder  => click on the file and edit.
  [image]

> Failed to set up deployment: Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub

- As mentioned above we need to authorize the GitHub Account. Also make sure AzureApp service is registered in `Authorized OAuth Apps` in GitHub.

In your `GitHub` Account => in the right pane`Settings` => left pane `applications` => `Authorized OAuth Apps`.

[image]

Comment: What to set up in GitHub if the Workflow uses ```Service Principal``` to create Azure resources?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in azure console (terminal-looking icon on top right).

```
Set-AzResource -PropertyObject @{token=$github_pat} -ResourceId /providers/Microsoft.Web/sourcecontrols/GitHub
```